# How to create Group By LINQ query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework and I have 3 linked tables
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhcve.png)

I can create query like this

```
purchase_number   album_name  purchase_amount  purchase_price
1                 name_1      5                1000
1                 name_2      10               2000
2                 name_1      3                1000
2                 name_3      7                1500
3                 name_2      2                2000
```

How can I create query like this using LINQ

```
purchase_number   purchase_price(purchase_price * purchase_amount)
1                 25000
2                 13500
3                 4000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where q is your original query:

```
var result = q
  .GroupBy(x=>x.purchase_number)
  .Select(x=>new { 
    purchase_number = x.Key, 
    purchase_price = x.Sum(z=>z.purchase_amount*z.purchase_price) 
  });
```

Optionally doing an orderby at the end to guarantee the order if that is a requirement.